# Remote desktop hangs on "Configuring session"

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

This has been [asked already](https://superuser.com/questions/366204/windows-remote-desktop-configuring-remote-session-closes-without-error) but none of the solutions provided is working for me.

The problem started as an interment thing, when it happened, I would wait for sometime and try again as it would work after a couple of minutes.

Now I've spent an entire day trying without luck. Just this forever loading bar.

[image]

I'm trying to access my Amazon EC2 Windows Server instance as I usually do. I didn't change the Security groups/firewall settings or anything. Running windows 10 PRO 64bit

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see the exact cause, by you can try:
1. Disable all redirect resource from MSTSC.exe before the connection.
2. Try to restart the remote desktop service remotely if you can RD to another EC2 instance.
3. Consider to apply all available updates on the server to upgrade the RDS conponents to the latest version.
4.  Check event log on the server, if any specific error maybe related with this problem.